# Showing Not Covered by Test if method throw exception junit mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, sonarqube, junit4

```
implementation class have two method :
test method call by test case and inside test() i call test2() which is throw exception, now I want 
to 
cover this method by test case but in sonar it showing not covered by test , so how i can covered this 
method:

 [service implementation class][1]

public void test()throws SystemException {
    LOGGER.info("Testing exception");
    test2(); //not covered by test
    LOGGER.info("Testing exception 2");//not covered by test
    System.out.print("hi");//not covered by test
}

public void test2() throws SystemException {
    LOGGER.info("Testing exception");
    throw new SystemException();
}
```

Test case: this is test which is call service.test1() method but in code coverage it is showing not
covered by test:

```
@Test(expected = SystemException.class)
public void test1() throws SystemException  {
   service.test();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're being very unclear about what exactly your problem is. When you refer to "this method" or "it", you have to be clear about exactly what that means.

Concerning your existing code, if you're wondering how to "cover" the last two lines of method "test", it's not possible to cover them.  In fact, it's not at all possible to execute those lines at all.  If method "test2" throws that exception, it will exit method "test2" along with method "test" without executing the rest of method "test".

To be clearer about what you're asking, you might try changing your method names to be a little more different, and refer to those method names explicitly.